# Where does jenkins store job and node configuration

Tags: tomcat, configuration, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I deployed jenkins in tomcat using war deployment with successful results. Configuring jobs & nodes is happened properly and CI works good. I was wondering where does the information about the job & nodes stored in jenkins.
Since i might want to take a periodic backup of the configuration data, to automate another CI in case first CI machine goes down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `~/.jenkins` by default, but this can be configured. `~` is the home directory of the user that runs the container (e.g. Tomcat). See the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) on how to change this (what I recommend).

Comment: thanks for the documentation link. as mentioned $JENKIN_HOME is what you need to set before running tomcat, jenkins automatically takes that path and start dumping configuration file sin that. I would highly recommend that since it makes sure you can either place that on NAS or do a scheduled backup for the config.

Answer (score 1):

In the directory pointed to by the %JENKINS_HOME% environment variable.

More [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins).